# Deleting part of a string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I want to delete part of a string found in a particular field.

For example, the entry in the field could be "01365320**APS**". The "APS" is what I am looking at deleting.

My question is, should I use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('fieldname','APS', 1)
```

Comment: Needs more context - what about the strings with "APS1234945", or "1234APS45689"?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

When you want to edit a field, you need an  `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname=REPLACE(fieldname,'APS','')
```

`REPLACE` is a string function that replaces every occurence of the 2nd string in the 1st string with the 3rd one.

Please try this with a `WHERE` clause first, to see if it is really what you want to do.

Comment: How do you make it delete upon duplicate entry?

Answer (score 16):

For **every** occurrence of APS, try this:

```
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column,'APS','');
```

Reference:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace