# delete complicated value from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

My table structure in the database;

Table "System_t"

```
id         |    Owner     |    System
===========================================
1          |    Joe       |    Registration
           |              |    Event             //contains new line
           |              |    Aims
-------------------------------------------
2          |    Rose      |    Ticket
           |              |    Elearning
```

NOTE : The data field "System" were saved from a Textarea box.

My problem is how am I going to delete only the "Event" data from the field "System"?

My table should be look like this when it is deleted;

```
id         |    Owner     |    System
===========================================
1          |    Joe       |    Registration
           |              |    Aims
-------------------------------------------
2          |    Rose      |    Ticket
           |              |    Elearning
```

Any idea how to do it without changing the table structure?

Comment: Does the `System` column always contain the text `Event` or is it a different event name in each cell?

Comment: Then if it's a different text in each cell, he'll surely manage it with PHP, not MYSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `UPDATE` statement with a `REPLACE` should be better in this case.

Look at this post, it might help you understand what I'm talking about :

[Deleting part of a string in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681910/deleting-part-of-a-string-in-mysql)

Comment: Actually, this is better than my regex answer since, well, regex is unnecessary for a fixed string :-) + 1 and deleting mine.

Comment: Yes, I though the REGEX solution was a bit complex for this kind of trick. But I have to add that, even if the OP doesn't want to talk about it, the structure of the table should be reviewed.

Comment: I still think you should be using like. On large tables what tsabz proposed won't be using any index.

Comment: What I'm proposing is just a way of doing the trick. He's free to modify the request adding any kind of `like` clause or whatever he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `delete` command to delete it:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Comment: Can't do that because it will delete all the data in the field "System"

Comment: Give me a minute . Let me just find out another way !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchQuery = "Event";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `System` FROM `System_t` WHERE `System` LIKE '%" . $searchQuery . "%'");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($arr = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
        $system = explode("\n", $arr[1]);
        $key = array_search($searchQuery, $system);
        if ($key !== false)
            unset($system[$key]);

        $system = implode("\n", $system);

        mysql_query("UPDATE `System_t` SET `System`='" . $system . "' WHERE `id`='" . $arr[0] . "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: I read from the question that the `Event` line will be a unique piece of text for each row rather than just the text `'Event'`.

Comment: `mysql_*` shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: @bendataclear LIKE '%text%' will find the rows even when there is a new line in between

Comment: @Shikiryu Yeah, but it is easier to explain it using mysql_*, isn't it?

Comment: @Ananth nope, at least use `mysqli_*`. Better use PDO, so that any beginners don't use `mysql_*` because some old dude find it easier. Let's **kill** `mysql_*` once and for all.

Comment: @Shikiryu gotcha! Will surely do from next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 update System_t su
       set su.System = replace(su.System, "Event", "") 
        where su.System like "%Event%";
```

I haven't taken the new lines into account I leave this for you as an easy exercise :).

Answer (score 0):

```
Update system_t SET system=REPLACE(system,'event','') WHERE system REGEXP '[[:<:]]event[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: Just notice there is a better solution provided by tsabz.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL, you coud use something like (because I believe there's no direct replace function as in MySQL):

```
UPDATE "System_t"
SET "System" = overlay("System" placing '' 
               from (position('Events' in "System")) 
               for 6)
WHERE "System" LIKE '%Events%'
```

You can see the description of the overlay and position functions here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-string.html

And 6 is the size of the string you are removing.

Anyway, I would recommend for you to create another table with, for example, (id, system_id, system_type), with system_id being a foreign key poiting to the other table. That way, you would have a better model and avoid a lot of inconsistency.