# SQL Server - conditionally delete part of a string within a field

Tags: sql-server

I checked both of these:

[Delete part of a field in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239190/delete-part-of-a-field-in-sql)

[Deleting part of a string in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681910/deleting-part-of-a-string-in-mysql)

but they're not *quite* what I need.

I've unfortunately inherited a table with a field full of comma-separated strings with no regard for format or order.  It's ugly. Now I need to get rid of a particular part of a string:

So let's say I have a table as such:

```
    Column1   Column2
    1         XRR01,MMEX1,XFR44
    2         XRR02,MMEX1
    3         MMEX1,GH345,XFR45,CFA34
    4         NMM22,MMEX1,XFR44
    5         MMEX1
    6         XFR55
```

I want to do an `UPDATE` to find and delete any instances of `MMEX1` from the `Column2` field, and keep the other parts intact.

So then I would be left with:

```
    Column1   Column2
    1         XRR01,XFR44
    2         XRR02
    3         GH345,XFR45,CFA34
    4         NMM22,XFR44
    5         NULL (or blank, doesn't really matter)
    6         XFR55
```

Is this possible?

Comment: My advice it to take the table you inherited and expand it so each Column1 value has separate rows for each of the possible Column2 values. Yes, this likely means changing whatever application this table supports, but it will be worth it. I promise. And it will take your problem here and make it MUCH simpler.

Comment: Trust me I know, and I fully plan to do so when deadlines aren't closely looming (when does that ever happen??!)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `Replace` function

```
select replace(replace(Column2,',MMEX1',''),'MMEX1,','') 
from Yourtable
```

`replace(Column2,',MMEX1','')` will remove the string in middle and last
`replace(Column2,'MMEX1,','')` will remove the string at the start

**Note :** storing comma sepearated value in a column is always a pain when comes to data processing. Try and change the table structure